# How to pass object containing list from View to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use a MVC project written with C#.

I've an object 'Recipe' that contains :

```
int id;
List<Ingredient> ingredientList;
String description;
//and so on
```

When I pass a 'Recipe' object from my controller to my view, the ingredient list contains well the different ingredients of my recipe. In my view, to save the ingredient list, I do this :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Ingredients)
```

But when I submit my form in my view, so It is going to my controller. And when I use the debugger to see what contains the current recipe, I notice that my ingredient list is empty. I don't know why.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: You cant use `@Html.HiddenFor()` on a complex object. You need to use a `for` loop and render inputs for each property of `Ingredients` (or is it `ingredientlist`?) but since you want only hidden inputs, whats the point of sending all that data to the client, then posting it all back again unchanged to the server. If you need it in the POST method, just get it from the repository again.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that the view only knows how to do a `HiddenFor` for basic types.

You could work around this with something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Ingredients) 
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem=>item.IngredientProperty1);
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem=>item.IngredientProperty2);
    //and so on for all the properties of your Ingredient class
}
```

With that said, you might be better advised to make a view model with only the properties you intend to edit as read/write properties of the class. You would then not be passing all the extra data around in http POST that wasnt needed.